# Spring Boot Modular Project: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Modular Spring Boot application following guidelines from : https://www.section.io/engineering-education/multi-module-architecture-with-spring-boot-and-maven/

However this article does not speak about application.properties files for different modules. I've included this in my **root application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

Here the root is a spring boot application and the data, service & controller are maven modules.

**Root pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dbiz</groupId>
    <artifactId>esuite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>esuite</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>eSuite project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>data</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>controller</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**Modules pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>controller</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.dbiz</groupId>
    <artifactId>esuite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dbiz</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dbiz</groupId>
        <artifactId>data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The other modules pom.xml files are similar.

**Stack Trace**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

2023-01-10T11:14:27.773+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] com.dbiz.esuite.EsuiteApplication        : Starting EsuiteApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 13664 (D:\eclipse-workspace\esuite\target\classes started by Dell in D:\eclipse-workspace\esuite)
2023-01-10T11:14:27.782+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] com.dbiz.esuite.EsuiteApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-10T11:14:31.986+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-10T11:14:32.210+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 33 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-10T11:14:38.609+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-10T11:14:38.647+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-10T11:14:38.647+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-01-10T11:14:39.413+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-10T11:14:39.416+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11128 ms
2023-01-10T11:14:39.553+05:00  WARN 13664 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-01-10T11:14:39.558+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-10T11:14:45.176+05:00  INFO 13664 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-10T11:14:45.236+05:00 ERROR 13664 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I've tried all the solution I can find on Stackoverflow and other forums however none of them is working for me. Any hints or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Made changes to the application.properties file by using `spring.datasource.hikari.url`

**New Application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=Mysql-spring.datasource.hikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
spring.datasource.hikari.username=root
spring.datasource.hikari.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Result**
Still getting the same error.

Comment: The problem is your project setup. You've included the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your root pom, as all the others use this as the parent the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` applies to that as well and thus not building a regular jar but a spring boot jar, which is different. You should create another module and only that module should have the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` the others should just build a a regular jar.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I included that plugin following a solution from someone on stackoverflow, However I get the same error with or without that plugin.

Comment: I am concerned about all the spaces surrounding the `=` signs

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Deleted the extra spaces around = signs, still getting the same error

Comment: `Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]` -> your configuration is not set up for hikari datasources. The pattern is different: `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")`

Comment: Still the problem is related to the fact that all your modules have the wrong structure. You should have 1 module that builds with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and contains the `application.properties`. That file should only exists once, also you should ditch the `maven-resource-plugin` as that is already applied. The proble is your structure and building. The root pom should be of type `pom` and not the default `jar` as well.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I added '@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")' on my sprig boot application class but it doesn't change anything, still getting the same error.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, The root pom type is pom, but I think I understand what you mean by having an additional module that builds with the spring-boot-maven plugin, can you guide me a little about how I should go about structuring the project for that?

Comment: No, you need `spring.datasource.hikari.url` in your properties file

Comment: @XtremeBaumer made the changes for `spring.datasource.hikari.url`, new application.properties is in the edited question however it causes the same error as before.

Comment: The regular `spring.datasource.url` will work. You can just add another module next to `controller`, `data` etc. named `app` which has all the other modules as a dependency, includes the configuration and builds the executable jar (and ofcourse contains the `application.properties`.

Comment: @M.Deinum should this app module be a maven module or spring boot project? All other modules are maven modules right now. And should I just run from main function in  root project?

Comment: Why wouldn't a spring boot project be a module? It is just a maven module with the Spring Boot plugin and a class with a main bootstrapping the application.

Answer (score -1):

The JPA (Java persistence API) is a java specification for ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) tools. The "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" dependency enables ORM in the context of the spring boot framework.

The JPA auto configuration feature of the spring boot application attempts to establish database connection using JPA Datasource. The JPA DataSource bean requires database driver to connect to a database.

The database driver should be available as a dependency in the pom.xml file. For the external databases such as Oracle, SQL Server, MySql, DB2, Postgres, MongoDB etc requires the database JDBC connection properties to establish the connection.

You need to configure the database driver and the JDBC connection properties to fix this exception -> Failed to configure a DataSource: ‘url’ attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class.

application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

By Programming :**Try this one, I built your demo project and ran it successfully using this one.**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude =  {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: He uses JPA and thus needs a datasource excluding it will not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I already tried this but I get a new error with this approach `A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.`

Comment: Try setting manual configuration for your JPA

Comment: @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    return sessionFactory;
}

Comment: If my answers suffice to your issue, kindly send me a verified like ! I'd really appreciate your return.